# Обособление оборотов, начинающихся со слов помимо, благодаря, за неимением и т. п

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги, обстоятельство

***Помимо*** смены платформы(,) стали известны некоторые подробности квестовой составляющей игры.

Нужна ли здесь запятая? На *Грамоте* пишут:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем предложении предлог *помимо* вводит **остоятельственный** оборот, который не попадает под рекомендации *Грамоты*, следовательно, запятая не нужна? Что вообще делать с такими предлогами?

Comment: Построено не совсем удачно. Розенталь бы не пропустил в печать. Надо бы перестроить предложение, например так: *Помимо того, что платформа меняется, стали известны некоторые подробности квестовой составляющей игры.*

Comment: @М_Г Я отпраил Розенталю на проверку, надеюсь, ответит.

Comment: @shampar А зачем Вы выделили слово? Там буква пропущена, я знаю. Или, может быть, это с каким-то определенным умыслом сделано?

Comment: Хотя узнал только после того, как Вы выделили. Кажется, я уловил намек)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Розенталя:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=251#pp251

> В зависимости **от смысловой нагрузки, степени распространения
>   оборота, близости к основной части предложения** и т. д. *могут
>   обособляться* (выделяться запятыми) существительные с предлогами или
>   предложными сочетаниями кроме, вместо, **помимо**, сверх, за
>   исключением, наряду с и др. (условно называемые дополнениями) с
>   ограничительным или расширительным значением, т. е. включения,
>   исключения, замещения...
>
> Обособление или необособление таких оборотов **факультативно**:
>
> *Многие из бойцов, **помимо своей винтовки**, были вооружены трофейными
>   автоматами (Пол.); Как бы человек ни стремился **помимо школы**, сам
>   по себе получить знания, он всё-таки будет, как говорят, самоучкой;*

В нашем случае не наблюдается *тесной связи* между дополнением и основной частью предложения (помимо известного нам факта смены платформы, поступили такие-то сведения), поэтому в исходном предложении я бы отделил соотв. фрагмент **запятой**, но не поставил бы её в приведённом к типичному "включению" варианте:

> Помимо новости о смене платформы пришли сведения о другом и третьем.

(помимо новости об одном пришли сведения о другом)

Comment: А я-то думал, что это обстоятельство. Ну, как обычно, к каждому предложению подход индивидуален.

Answer (score 1):

Есть хороший словарь для выяснения сомнительных случаев:

**Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д. Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений**

Например, [вот здесь](http://padaread.com/?book=182745&pg=278) прямая ссылка на слово "помимо". Там сказано, что оборот с "помимо" является дополнением со значением исключения или включения. В первом случае он обособляется, во втором — нет.

В вашем случае это включение, ср. "в дополнение к новостям о смене платформы стали известны..." (надеюсь, я правильно понял смысл предложения — оно построено не совсем удачно). Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Удачная фамилия у автора) Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Такие обороты не обособляются **в нераспространенных предложениях**, например: **Помимо изменения платформы** были и другие дополнения.

В остальных случаях оборот, как правило, обособляется:

**Помимо смены платформы, стали известны некоторые (новые?) подробности квестовой составляющей игры.**

В данном предложении должны быть указаны и другие **изменения,** тогда оно будет правильно построено.

Comment: А вот у Вас уже более универсальное правило, спасибо и Вам.